# Xarray/Dask: map_block computation - variable size inconsistency

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, python-xarray

For a workable example of Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd
import xesmf as xe

from dask.distributed import Client

def diurnal_cycle_model(hours, intercept, coef_cos, coef_sin):
    return intercept + coef_cos * np.cos(2 * np.pi * hours / 24) + coef_sin * np.sin(2 * np.pi * hours / 24)

def harm_fit(data):
    data = data.fillna(0)
    ndim = len(data.dims)
    hours = [3,9,15,21]
    
    params = xr.apply_ufunc(curve_fit, diurnal_cycle_model, hours, data,
                            input_core_dims=[[], ['step'], ['step']],
                            output_core_dims=[['param'], ['param1', 'param2']],
                            vectorize=True, dask='parallelized', output_dtypes=[float, float])
    
    intercept, coef_cos, coef_sin = params[0].isel(param=0), params[0].isel(param=1), params[0].isel(param=2)

    hours_reconstructed = xr.DataArray(data=np.arange(0,24),dims=['step'],coords={'step':pd.timedelta_range(start='0 hour',end='23 hours',freq='1H')})
    dc_reconstructed = diurnal_cycle_model(hours_reconstructed.expand_dims(dim={'time':intercept.time,'number':intercept.number,'lat':intercept.lat,'lon':intercept.lon},axis=(1,2,3,4)),
                                           intercept,
                                           coef_cos,
                                           coef_sin)
    return dc_reconstructed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s2s_fcst = xr.DataArray(data=np.random.normal(size=(21,21,4,21,47)),
                            dims=['time','number','step','lat','lon'],
                            coords=dict(time=pd.date_range(start='2017-10-02',periods=21),
                                        step=pd.timedelta_range(start='3h',end='21h',freq='6h'),
                                        number=np.arange(0,21),
                                        lat=np.arange(15,-16.5,-1.5),
                                        lon=np.arange(90,160.5,1.5)),
                            name='tp')
    s2s_fit = xr.DataArray(dims=['time','number','step','lat','lon'],
                           coords=dict(time=s2s_fcst.time,number=s2s_fcst.number,
                                       step=pd.timedelta_range(start='0 day',end='46 day',freq='1 h'),
                                       lat=s2s_fcst.lat,lon=s2s_fcst.lon),
                           name='tp_fit')
    
    client = Client(n_workers=4)
    
    for l in range(0,2): #range(0,46):
        print('Lead '+str(l))
        rain_6hr = s2s_fcst[:,:,4*l:4*l+4,:,:]
        
        reshaped_ds = rain_6hr.transpose('step','time','number','lat','lon')
        reshaped_ds_chunk = reshaped_ds.chunk({'time': 3,'number':3})
        print(reshaped_ds_chunk)
        template = (xr.DataArray(data=np.zeros(shape=(24,21,21,21,47)),
                                dims=['step','time','number','lat','lon'],
                                coords=dict(time=s2s_fcst.time,number=s2s_fcst.number,
                                            step=pd.timedelta_range(start='0 hour',end='23 hours',freq='1H'),
                                            lat=s2s_fcst.lat,lon=s2s_fcst.lon))
                      .chunk({'time': 3,'number':3}))
        print(template)
        dc_harm_fit = reshaped_ds_chunk.map_blocks(harm_fit, template=template).compute(scheduler=client)
        print(dc_harm_fit)
        dc_harm_fit_transpose = dc_harm_fit.transpose('time','number','step','lat','lon')
        print(dc_harm_fit_transpose)
```

For this code, I am trying to fit the forecast rainfall data to the diurnal cycle model defined as `diurnal_cycle_model(hours, intercept, coef_cos, coef_sin)`.

1. Data structure: `s2s_fcst` is forecast rainfall data with a 6-hourly time step (`step` dimension). It has forecast initial time `time`, forecast time steps `step`, ensemble members `number`, and latitude/longitude. Here, data is substituted with random numbers for demonstration.
2. I am trying to fit the diurnal cycle on the `step` dimension for each forecast day, i.e. the first forecast days (loop over `l`) include 0-3rd timesteps of `step`, and the second forecast days include the 4-7th timesteps of `step`.
3. `harm_fit` requires a long computation time. Therefore, I chunk the data and input it to  `map_blocks(harm_fit)`.
4. In `harm_fit`, we regress the 4 forecast timesteps on the `diurnal_cycle_model` and obtain the regression coefficients. Then we reconstruct the hourly rainfall (24 time steps, with 1-hour frequency). Therefore, the output data after `harm_fit` has the `step` with 24 steps instead of the input of 4 steps. The `template` for the `map_block` has a step dimension of 24 hours.
5. After `compute()`, the error message occurs as follows:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError
> replacement data must match the Variable's shape. replacement data has shape (3, 21, 147, 47, 24); Variable has shape (24, 21, 21, 21, 47)
> File "/Users/waynetsai/Desktop/test.py", line 62, in 
> `dc_harm_fit = reshaped_ds_chunk.map_blocks(harm_fit, template=template).compute(scheduler=client)`

How could I fix the issue? What's wrong with the code?

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape mismatch between your "harm_fit" function's output and the template you're giving "map_blocks" is the root of the problem. While the variable (template) has shape (24, 21, 21, 21, 47), the error indicates that the replacement data (the output of harm_fit) has shape (3, 21, 147, 47, 24).

This shape mismatch is most likely caused by the fact that the input chunk size (3 steps) and the output of "harm_fit" (24 steps) have different step dimension sizes. It appears that the output has a different step dimension size when using "map_blocks", even though the function is supposed to produce chunks that match the size of the input chunks.

Making sure that the "input chunk" size and the "harm_fit" output have the same step dimension size is necessary to correct this. The "harm_fit" function can be changed to only return the pertinent steps to accomplish this, or the logic in "harm_fit" and the template can be modified to account for the various step sizes.

I hope that this helps.

EDIT:

Here's a modified version of your code using "map" instead of "map_blocks":

```
def harm_fit(data):
    data = data.fillna(0)
    ndim = len(data.dims)
    hours = [3, 9, 15, 21]

    params = xr.apply_ufunc(curve_fit, diurnal_cycle_model, hours, data,
                            input_core_dims=[['step'], ['step'], ['step']],
                            output_core_dims=[['param'], ['param1', 'param2']],
                            vectorize=True, dask='parallelized', output_dtypes=[float, float])

    intercept, coef_cos, coef_sin = params[0].isel(param=0), params[0].isel(param=1), params[0].isel(param=2)

    # create a new template for the output
    template = (xr.DataArray(data=np.zeros(shape=(24, 21, 21, 21, 47)),
                             dims=['step', 'time', 'number', 'lat', 'lon'],
                             coords=dict(time=s2s_fcst.time, number=s2s_fcst.number,
                                         step=pd.timedelta_range(start='0 hour', end='23 hours', freq='1H'),
                                         lat=s2s_fcst.lat, lon=s2s_fcst.lon))
                .chunk({'time': 3, 'number': 3}))

    # apply the function using map
    dc_harm_fit = xr.map_blocks(harm_fit, data, template=template)

    return dc_harm_fit
```

Comment: Hi @Al1nuX, I appreciate your response! I have a follow-up question: since the purpose of `harm_fit` is to regress and reconstruct original data, the dimension size of the output must be different from the input. Do you mean that this is inappropriate for map_block even if I specify a new template for the output?

Comment: @Wayne, If your function produces output with a different size, you may encounter shape mismatch issues, as Dask assumes the output will fit into the blocks defined by the input chunks.

However, if you need to generate output with a different size, you might consider a different approach, such as using the map function instead of map_blocks. The map function applies a function to each element of the Dask array without the requirement that the output has the same block size as the input.